# Displaying multiple entries on a database into an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemtemplate

I am trying to display multiple lines from a database into an aspx page. My aspx page name is news.aspx and my table is called news.
I have configured my aspx with the code to display what I want my page to look like. I have attached an image to show I would like it to look like when the page is loaded. The aspx page uses ItemTemplate & asp:Repeater to display the multiple lines.

My aspx page is configured as follows:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group alert alert-info">
                <asp:label runat="server" ID="lblNewsEdits">Latest Sports & Social News Items</asp:label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>
                Title:
                <asp:Literal ID="litTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                (<asp:Literal ID="litDatePosted" runat="server"></asp:Literal>)
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>
                Title:
                <asp:Literal ID="litNewsContent" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
               </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

My aspx.cs page is configured to pull the information from the news table, I want three column of data to be display in the aspx page (Title, DatePosted and NewsContent). 
For the three lines below, I am getting error: "The name "..." does not exist in the current context.

- litTitle.text = reader ["Title"].ToString();
- litDatePosted.Text = reader["Date Posted"].ToString();
- litNewsContent.Text = reader["News Content"].ToString();

The aspx.cx page is configured as follows:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        string getNewsQuery = "SELECT Id, Title, DataPosted, Newsontent FROM News WHERE Id = @id";


        //get email based on id
        SqlCommand getNewsCommand = new SqlCommand(getNewsQuery, connection);
        object id = null;
        getNewsCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = getNewsCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            litTitle.txt = reader ["Title"].ToString();
            litDatePosted.Text = reader["Date Posted"].ToString();
            litNewsContent.Text = reader["News Content"].ToString();

        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();

    }
```

My database table is configured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[News] (
[Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]       NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[DatePosted]  DATE           NOT NULL,
[NewsContent] NTEXT          NOT NULL,
[IsRead]      BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to format your code like this:

```
litTitle.txt = reader["Title"].ToString();
litDatePosted.Text = reader["DatePosted"].ToString();
litNewsContent.Text = reader["NewsContent"].ToString();
```

Also in your sql query you have a typo in the SELECT statement, you typed 
'Newsontent' instead of 'NewsContent'

**EDIT:** 
Try using the grid view instead of table. GridView should format it selfe acording to the sorce provided by the SqlDataAdapter

```
 protected void Pageaaa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    string getNewsQuery = "SELECT Id, Title, DataPosted, Newsontent FROM News WHERE Id = @id";


    //get email based on id
    SqlCommand getNewsCommand = new SqlCommand(getNewsQuery, connection);
    object id = null;
    getNewsCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = getNewsCommand.ExecuteReader();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dataTable);
    GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    connection.Close();
    da.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for pointing out the typo, I corrected this and formatted the code like you said but I am still getting: The name "..." does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the big update, I am now getting Grideview1 does't exist in the current context

Comment: Ok, chech your aspx file and make shure that element id of the grid view is 'GridView1'

Comment: This is how i have my GridView implemented in the aspx file. Don't forget about the runat="server" property  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Style="float: left;">       </asp:GridView>

Comment: Thanks Levidoom, that worked perfectly. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Glad to help :D